# how to Access the jquery variable in html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my javascript file check.js which contains the following function

```
function fun2(userid)
{

$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url:'ex.php',
    data:{userid : userid},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);


    }
});
}
```

userid is my username and it goes to the ex.php  file given below

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
$src1= $_POST['userid']; 
echo $_SESSION['userid']; 
}

?>
```

the Php code returns the userid to jquery after creating a session i.e the data which i have used.Now i want to use this data in the html file to display

```
my.html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li>
 <a href="">
  Account
  </a>                   
  </li
```

i want to replace the account with my **data** variable from the javascript function

```
check.js = /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/js/check.js
ex.php = /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ex.php
my.html = /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/myhtml.html
```

above are my file locations
Can any body guide how to keep data value in place of account in the html so that i can display on my ui

Comment: $('ul li a').html(data); //instead of alert(data);

Comment: @RockySims tried but nor working

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

`$('ul.nav li a').html(data)`

```
function fun2(userid)
{

$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url:'ex.php',
    data:{userid : userid},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);

        // put it in here
        $('ul.nav li a').html(data)
    }
});
}
```

Comment: ('ul.nav li a') .Can u tell me what does it mean

Comment: `$('ul.nav li a').html(data)` means to put `data` string inside `a` element under `ul.nav` and `li`.
maybe the `data` that you send is not a string. it can be a JSON object or even an empty return from your PHP script